# Is there a 'save' method on a 'formset' or 'form' ? (Not a modelform or modelformfactory)

Tags: python, django, django-forms

This is my forms.py file:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    data = forms.CharField()
    def clean(self):
        if any(self.errors):
            return
        value = self.cleaned_data['data']
        if int(value) % 2 != 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("Please enter an even number"))
```

This is my views.py file:

```
def modelform(request):
    AuthorFormSet = formset_factory(MyForm, formset=BaseAuthorFormSet, extra=3)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        forms = AuthorFormSet(request.POST)
        if forms.is_valid():
            #forms.save() --> IS THERE A SAVE() METHOD ON FORMSET ? 
            return HttpResponse("Saved successfullly")

    else:
        forms = AuthorFormSet()
    context = {
        'form' : forms,
        'non_form_errors' : forms.non_form_errors(),
    }
    return render(request, 'modelform.html', context)
```

What I want to know is can we do something like `'forms.save()'` as in views.py file for a formset?

And what if it was just a form, could we do the save method ?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, formset has `save()` method so just call:

```
if forms.is_valid():
    forms.save()
```

Check out django doc about [use model formset in a view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-model-formset-in-a-view).

Comment: I am not asking about a 'modelformset', I am asking about just a 'formset'.